# Custom DatePicker using UIPIckerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am new to ios development. I am making a custom datepicker using uipickerview. I have datesArray to be used as a data source for uipickerview.

I want to know how to show only Labels : today,tomorrow,Fri,Sat,Sun,Mon,Tues for current week and rest dates in format "EEE, LLL d".

I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
for(int i=0;i<22;i++)
{
    NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60 * 24 * i];
    NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, LLL d"];
    if(myDate==now)
    {
        NSString *myDateString=@"today";
         [datesArray addObject:myDateString];
    }
    else
    {
    NSString *myDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];

    [datesArray addObject:myDateString];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.Hope it helps

```
 NSString *dateFromWS = @"2013-10-16";//im taking it as static you have to take string coming from webservice

 for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
 {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60 * 24 * i];
    NSDate *now = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateFromWS];
    NSDate *tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24 * 1 sinceDate:now];
    //NSDate *dummy = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24 * 1 sinceDate:now];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, LLL d"];
    NSString *loopDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
    NSString *today = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSString *tomorrowString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tomorrow];
    if ([loopDate isEqualToString:today]) {
        [datesArray addObject:@"today"];
    } else if ([loopDate isEqualToString:tomorrowString]) {
       [datesArray addObject:@"tomorrow"]; 
    } else if ((i/7) < 1) {
        [datesArray addObject:[loopDate substringToIndex:3]];
    } else {
        [datesArray addObject:loopDate];
    }
 }
```

Comment: how to use date from webservice as starting date (current date) for this?

Comment: can you post the date that comes from webservice i need to know in which format your date comes

Comment: That would probably best be another question. I gather this involves the picker delegate and datasource more than this array.

Comment: Here it is: 2013-10-16

Comment: @DeanDavids I agree with you

Comment: The above code picks date from ios device. If i set iphone's date to 21 dec 13, i see next 21 days then. However i always want my server's date as the starting date!

Comment: Ok i'll update my answer in 5 minutes.But are you sure that the date comes in same format everytime? and are you able to store the date coming from webservice in a global string?

Comment: I suppose you could change *now to server date and tomorrow to dateWithTimeIntervalSinceDate:

Comment: Ok..I store it in NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myDate==now)
```

is comparing 2 pointers not 2 dates. You need to use the below code

```
if([myDate compare:now] == NSOrderedSame)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Simon's pointer issue, your dates will include the time info and so is never likely to be identical. May be the same day but not the same time. You need to find if the day matches. I do this by:

```
for(int i=0;i<22;i++)
{
    NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60 * 24 * i];
    NSDate *myDateNoTime = nil;
    // Note: Create sysCal as a property so it is not being repeatedly recreated here
    [self.sysCal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&myDateNoTime interval:nil forDate:myDate];
    NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
    NSDate *todayDateNoTime = nil;
    [self.sysCal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&todayDateNoTime interval:nil forDate:now];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, LLL d"];

    if([myDateNoTime isEqualToDate:todayDateNoTime])
    {
        NSString *myDateString=@"today";
         [datesArray addObject:myDateString];
    }
    else
    {
    NSString *myDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];

    [datesArray addObject:myDateString];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your server date requirement and, in my opinion, a better way of handling a picker, I would put this in the datasource method instead.

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *resultString = nil;
    NSDate *myDate = [self dateForRow:row];
    NSDate *myDateNoTime = nil;
    // Note: Create sysCal as a property so it is not being repeatedly recreated here
    [self.sysCal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&myDateNoTime interval:nil forDate:myDate];
    NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
    NSDate *todayDateNoTime = nil;
    [self.sysCal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&todayDateNoTime interval:nil forDate:now];

    if([myDateNoTime isEqualToDate:todayDateNoTime])
    {
       resultString = @"Today";
    } else {
       // Note: using property for date formatter so I am not repeatedly creating here
       resultString = [self.dayFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
    }

    return resultString;
}
```

To determine date for the row use:

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromRow:(NSInteger)inRow {
   NSDateComponents *daysToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   [daysToAdd setCalendar:self.sysCal];
   NSInteger daysCalc = (-1 * (inRow -2));
   [daysToAdd setDay:daysCalc];
   NSDate *resultDate = nil;

   NSDate *calcDate = [self.sysCal dateByAddingComponents:daysToAdd 
                                                   toDate:self.myServerDate 
                                                  options:0];

   [self.sysCal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&resultDate interval:nil forDate:calcDate];

   return resultDate;
}
```

I suppose you are already set with the way you are doing it but I think you would find this more flexible, no limit to 21 days before or after the server date. Aircode, excuse any typos or syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.0

```
for i in 0..<22 {
    var myDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 60 * 24 * i)
    var now = Date()
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, LLL d"

    if myDate == now {
       var myDateString = "today"
       datesArray.append(myDateString)
    } else {
       var myDateString: String = dateFormatter.string(from: myDate)
       datesArray.append(myDateString)
   }
}
```